# How to get GridView.Selected Item's Scroll Position in Windows 8 Metro App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I am selecting gridview item using code, so I also need my gridview to Scrolls at selected item's position ,  I tried GridView.ScrollintoPosition() but it is not working . 
IS there any way to get the **Scroll position** of SelectedItem so that I can scroll it using **scrollViewer1.ScrollToHorizontalOffsetWithAnimation()**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few aspects here.

1. I think just `gridView.ScrollIntoView(gridView.SelectedItem)` should work. It's a bit asynchronous, so the code wouldn't immediately see it scrolled, but if you do something like `await Task.Delay(100)` - you might be able to see the `ScrollViewer` offset updated..
2. If you want an animated scroll - you can use WinRT XAML Toolkit's `ScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffsetWithAnimation()` extension or if you are targeting Windows 8.1 - you can use the new `ScrollViewer.ChangeView()` method that supports animated scroll.

   1. You need to get the instance of the `ScrollViewer` in the `GridView` template first. You can either do it using `GetTemplatePart()` or with the `VisualTreeHelper`.
   2. Now you need to get the position of the UI container of the `SelectedItem` in the `ScrollViewer`. To do that you first need the container itself, which you can get using `var container = gv.ContainerFromItem(gv.SelectedItem)`, but if the `ItemsPanel` of the `GridView` is virtualized - you might not be able to do that because the `SelectedItem` might not have its UI container. I would simply do the non-animated scroll in that case for many reasons - mainly performance, but if you really have to - you might be able to calculate the position based on the index of the `SelectedItem` in the collection of items and item size, but it might be a bit complicated.
   3. Once you get the container you can get its position with something like `var horizontalOffset = gridViewItem.TransformToVisual(scrollViewer).TransformPoint(new Point()).X;`
   4. At this point you should be able to scroll to the offset using the method you like.

Comment: Thanks @Filip Skakun, This is very helpful, I am using WinRT XAML Toolkit's 

As you said, selecteditem wasn't have container so I used index of the  selected item , calculated scroll effect for one item and using these info I was able to achieve animating movement to selecteditem.